Is it possible to host a S3 website that is only accessible from within a VPC?
I've seen some similar questions, and so far there doesn't seem to be a way to do this, so this question is for further digging, or even a challenge for anyone to accomplish this.
The objective is to host a website from an S3 bucket, that is only accessible from within a VPC (e.g. using a VPN). And as a bonus, use a custom domain, instead of *.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

Using VPC Endpoint does not help, since they do not work with S3 websites, only REST endpoints.
Setting a bucket as a static website needs to allow public access and define a bucket policy to allow public access. Even if attempting to restrict it with a Constraint to a VPC on the bucket policy, it does not work.
It is possible to set the bucket to private and create a Cloudfront Distribution with access to it via Origin Access Control (OAC). But after this, the Cloudfront Endpoint is public. I'm not sure if using WAF (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35518936/14643464) it is possible to restrict to request coming from inside a VPC (or from a VPCs CIDR)

Related: Restricting access to a specific VPC.

From Controlling access from VPC endpoints with bucket policies - Amazon Simple Storage Service:

Restricting access to a specific VPC
You can create a bucket policy that restricts access to a specific VPC by using the aws:SourceVpc condition. This is useful if you have multiple VPC endpoints configured in the same VPC, and you want to manage access to your Amazon S3 buckets for all of your endpoints.
The following is an example of a policy that denies access to awsexamplebucket1 and its objects from anyone outside VPC vpc-111bbb22. If the specified VPC isn't used, the policy denies all access to the bucket. This statement doesn't grant access to the bucket. To grant access, you must add a separate Allow statement. The vpc-111bbb22 condition key doesn't require an ARN for the VPC resource, only the VPC ID.

{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policy1415115909153",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPC-only",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:*",
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"],
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {
           "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-111bbb22"
         }
       }
     }
   ]
}

I don't think you'd be able to do it with a custom domain, however.

Does this work when the bucket is used for website hosting, or only for the REST endpoints?

This does not work. The bucket had a policy with 3 entries: allow all, deny if not from vpc and allow if from VPC. Website returned a 403 forbidden as was not able to use the console to interact with the bucket (expected as said in the documentation, but still, a pain). Had to delete a policy from using the CLI from an instance inside the VPC. So the policy is there, working, but not working for the website.

A Deny will overrule an Allow, so you can test the policy without the Deny to confirm that it is granting access and then put the Deny back to confirm it is denying access. It sounds like "deny if not from vpc" is not successfully recognising the source as the VPC when using an S3 endpoint. Thus, it seems like the problem is with the combination of using an S3 Static Website endpoint while also attempting to restrict by VPC.

My goal was to host our modified version of this: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/runbooks on S3, and not make it publicly available.
But it seems it goes beyond the capabilities of the S3 service. Thanks for the help and the attempts John!

Can you possibly just point it to S3 using normal S3 URLs, rather than the website endpoint? It behaves exactly the same except for defaulting to an index page when a directory is specified. Good luck!
